# How do I create an animated number counter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to create a number counter that animates from a starting value to an end value. I've looked into using a Timer but can't seem to animate/update state properly. Including the decimal value would be great, but a simple integer animation is fine.

[Number counter that needs to animate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCcvo.png)

```
double _mileCounter = 643.6;

_animateMileCounter() {
  Duration duration = new Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  return new Timer(duration, _updateMileCounter);
}

_updateMileCounter() {
  setState(() {
    _mileCounter += 1;
  });
}
```

How would I increment the counter X number of times (with animation)? Similar to how a car's odometer increments.

Comment: By animate you mean, "print matching values from start value to end value according to some function of time"? In that case you could use a `Tween`.

Comment: Perhaps if you share some source code you might get some specific suggestions as to where you are going wrong or how you should proceed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use an `AnimationController` with an `AnimatedBuilder` to rebuild your text when the controller changes. Here's an example that increments the miles when the floating action button is pressed (`double.toStringAsFixed` to get the decimal to show), with a curve on the animation speed:

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.purple),
        home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  double _miles = 0.0;

  @override initState() {
    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
    );
    _animation = _controller;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextTheme textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Material(
        color: const Color.fromRGBO(246, 251, 8, 1.0),
        child: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              new AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _animation,
                builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                  return new Text(
                    _animation.value.toStringAsFixed(1),
                    style: textTheme.display4.copyWith(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  );
                },
              ),
              new Text(
                  "MILES",
                  style: textTheme.display1.copyWith(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.directions_run),
        onPressed: () {
          Random rng = new Random();
          setState(() {
            _miles += rng.nextInt(20) + 0.3;
            _animation = new Tween<double>(
                begin: _animation.value,
                end: _miles,
            ).animate(new CurvedAnimation(
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              parent: _controller,
            ));
          });
          _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
        }
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

For anyone still looking, you can use `ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget`.

Here is an example of an int counter. Works analogously for doubles.

```
class AnimatedCount extends ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget {
  final int count;

  AnimatedCount({
    Key key,
    @required this.count,
    @required Duration duration,
    Curve curve = Curves.linear
  }) : super(duration: duration, curve: curve, key: key);

  @override
  ImplicitlyAnimatedWidgetState<ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget> createState() => _AnimatedCountState();
}

class _AnimatedCountState extends AnimatedWidgetBaseState<AnimatedCount> {
  IntTween _count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text(_count.evaluate(animation).toString());
  }

  @override
  void forEachTween(TweenVisitor visitor) {
    _count = visitor(_count, widget.count, (dynamic value) => new IntTween(begin: value));
  }
}
```

Just rebuild the widget with a new value and it automatically animates there.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is no point in rebuilding what already exists.

Comment: Here's a [gist of an animated countdown](https://gist.github.com/Nolence/b7d43cd9ad25d614f52aba2c74a597fd) I used to cover both `int` and `double` just in case it saves someone some trouble

Comment: I need to figure out how it exactly works.. but I was able to modify it to work for what I need, Thank you

Comment: can someone modify this code to support newer flutter version (2.5.x)?

Comment: Updated for null-safety:
https://gist.github.com/bluemix/4c932e8c4a1cd6f497a4353d9e536f57

Answer (score 9):

You can use Countup package.

```
Countup(
  begin: 0,
  end: 7500,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
  separator: ',',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 36,
  ),
)
```

https://pub.dev/packages/countup

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this plugin [countup: ^0.1.3](https://pub.dev/packages/countup/example)

```
  import 'package:countup/countup.dart';

         Countup(
              begin: 100,
              end: 8000,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
              separator: ',',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 36,
                fontweight : Fontweight.bold,
              ),
            ),
```

[image]